# Button handler when internet connection lost

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a gridview which takes data from JSON data with links http://..../mobileapp/GetPostByCategoryXMLa?term_id=(item_id)
I would like if there is no Internet connection when I click on the "Try Again", it can refresh the page again (when there is a connection nternet).
XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="refreshBtn" Margin="0,15,0,0" Foreground="White" Width="100" Height="40" Content="Try Again" Background="#FF3C3C3C" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Click="refreshBtn_Click"/>
```

Full Code:

```
public sealed partial class FurnitureCategory : Page
{ 
    private ObservableCollection<Furniture> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Furniture>();

    public FurnitureCategory()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //FurnitureHome item = e.Parameter as FurnitureHome;
        Furniture detail = e.Parameter as Furniture;
        StoreDetail(int.Parse(detail.ID));//send id
        pageTitle.Text = detail.Title.ToString();
    }

    private async void StoreDetail(int id)
    {
        statusKosong.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        koneksiErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        requestErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
        {
            loading.IsActive = true;
            try
            {
                Furniture detail = new Furniture();

                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                string urlPath = "http://.../mobileapp/GetPostByCategoryXMLa?term_id="+id;

                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {

                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    loading.IsActive = false;
                    RequestException();
                }

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["posts"].GetArray();

                foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData1)
                {

                    JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();

                    double menuId = groupObject["post_id"].GetNumber();
                    string title = groupObject["post_title"].GetString();
                    string image = groupObject["featured_image"].GetString();
                    string deskripsi = groupObject["post_clean"].GetString();

                    Furniture file = new Furniture();
                    file.ID = menuId.ToString();
                    file.Title = title;
                    file.Gambar = image;
                    file.Deskripsi = deskripsi;

                    datasource.Add(file);
                }

                if (jsonData1.Count > 0)
                {
                    itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
                }
                else
                {
                    loading.IsActive = false;
                    statusKosong.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                loading.IsActive = false;
                RequestException();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            loading.IsActive = false;
            ConnectionException();
        }
    }

    private void ConnectionException()
    {
        koneksiErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void RequestException()
    {
        requestErrorStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void refreshBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Furniture detail =  new Furniture();
        StoreDetail(int.Parse(detail.ID));
    }

    private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Furniture itemDetail = e.ClickedItem as Furniture;
        DetailId.Text = itemDetail.ID;
        DetailJudul.Text = itemDetail.Title;
        DetailDeskripsi.Text = itemDetail.Deskripsi;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FurnitureDetail), itemDetail);
    }

    private void Image_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loading.IsActive = false;
    }

    private void cover_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loading.IsActive = false;
    }

    private void cover_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        loading.IsActive = true;
    }

    private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

}

Furniture class:

```
class Furniture
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Gambar { get; set; }

        public string Deskripsi { get; set; }
    }
```

By using the code above does not work and display an error message:
[image: error message]

How to handle it?
Note: 
item_id taken from the data ID on the previous page for the item that has been selected by the user,

Comment: You are creating a new object `detail` and accessing it's ID `detail.ID` which is null. That's why you are getting `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Can you fix my code? How to get id from method StoreDetail (int id)?

Comment: what this furniture class does?

Comment: Furniture class is to retrieve data from JSON from the server using the link. I've added a class Furniture in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

In the RefreshBtn_Click, you've creating a new Button, but this won't give the detail ID value anymore, since it's a new one (it won't get/recieve anything).
Though, it also does make me wonder why you make a furniture class, call a method, and make another furniture class and giving it the same 'detail' name.

Try making a furniture class where the detail ID is declared.
This could eventually happen outside of both methods, by declaring it at the start.

Comment: In the method StoreDetail (int id) also contain Furniture class. How do I declare id on refreshBtn? I give the full code on my post

Comment: That's depending on how you use it, but I'll give a parameter to the

Comment: Sorry, accidently clicked. But I will give a parameter to the class right when I made it. , like: "Furniture f = new furniture(int 1)". and then in the class itself, it'll put the parameter to the variable.

Comment: can you correct my code? I've changed Furniture Furniture detail = new (); became Furniture detail = new Furniture (int id); but an error message Syntax error, ',' expected and Invalid expression term 'int'

Comment: Have you made sure the parameter is declared in the furniture class as well? in the furniture class, you also have to make a furnitune method where you declare the int parameter. and inside that method, you give the parameter to the variable in the furniture class.